# In HPGOF, why is the fake school name not written on Harry's parchment?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter and TGOF, each person was instructed to "write their name and school clearly on a slip of parchment and drop it into the Goblet" by Dumbledore. So why is the name of the fake school not written in the parchment with Harry's name when it comes back out?

Dumbledore is the one who reads each name out when the Goblet chooses each champion, and he doesn't know all of these children. Viktor Krum is famous, and I guess he could guess from the names which school each champion belongs to, but surely the school names are just still on the parchment, as they were written?